# wake up app after terminate

Tags: ios, swift

i want to wake up my app after app terminated using background modes...
i know using location update and push notifications we can do.but i don't to use those. apart from those is their any way to wakeup my app.

actually i need to connect my app with websocket even app was terminated.

is their any way to wakeup app using core motions. or using microphone(i mean if app catches any data of voice(sound))..

can any one explain app life cycle (when it will wakeup and when it will sleep)

thanks u

Comment: This is unfortunately not possible. You can use some features like locations, waypoint monitoring, beacon stuff, which wakes your app up for a small timeline.

Comment: oops... i need to track device motion activity (stationary, walking, running, in-vehicle) even app is killed or is not in use.. how to achieve this without updating location... is their any background modes are available to wake up app (not using location and push notification)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if there is a way (actually there are some tricks with beacons but user would have to be in the range of beacon specified by you) it shouldn't be used like so.

If your app is kind of weather service or newsfeed, iOS device will be woken up at intervals specified by you (not less than 1h) to check for necessary data.

Using microphone or core motion to wake up your app probably won't pass apple review.

To fully answer your question I would have to know reason for background mode.

Comment: thanks for your response 
actually i want device motion activities even app killed. but am not sure core motion activity hasn't work after app terminated. but i need to update every second motion activity event app is not in use...
is their any way achieve this..

Answer (score 0):

No once app is terminated you don't have any access to app until app is opened by user. Even location update and push notifications only work in background.

Comment: Before down voting the answer please tell me how you will do it.

Comment: no dude may be way to achieve.. am not sure. but how facebook and whatsapp are achieving background modes...

Comment: Background mode is different than terminate mode. App terminate means app is not running now. App in background means app is running but in background. In my answer I already told app can run in background but you cannot do any action when app is terminated.

Comment: iOS is different from android and is having many restrictions.

Comment: can u say what are the those restrictions compare to andriod...
i want to achieve this is their any way..

Comment: See I studied about this topic more than 4 months. But it is strictly restricted by apple to use app when app is terminated. This cannot be achieved in any way. But there is one way called pushkit. I don't know much about that. You can learn more about that.

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirement "i need to track device motion activity", you could use the queryActivityStarting() provided by [apple API's](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmmotionactivitymanager/1615929-queryactivitystarting).
This gathers and returns historical motion data for the specified time period:

```
let activityManager = CMMotionActivityManager()
activityManager.queryActivityStarting(from: lastTimeAppCollectedData, to: now, to: queue) { (activities, error) in}
```

This returns you an array of activities/error that happened in the given period

It still wont wake your app up, but will allow you to query the events after they happened.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CLRegion for geofencing as soon as user exit the region boundary, your app will get open with didExit delegate of CLRegion and after that you can use startActivityUpdates of CMMotionActivityManager to keep your app open till you want.

Resources:
[Region Monitoring](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html)